# Is it possible sort a type's properties returned from Type.GetProperties() using attributes?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, custom-attributes

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx),

> **Type.GetProperties()**
>   The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies.

Can the properties be annotated in some way (custom attribute, maybe) so that you could do something like this?

```cs
var properties = typeof(myClass).GetProperties()
.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(Func<VoodooOrdinalAttribute>);
```

with

```cs
public class MyClass
{
   [VoodooOrdinalAttribute(2)] public string Color { get; set;}
   [VoodooOrdinalAttribute(3)] public string Shape { get; set;}
   [VoodooOrdinalAttribute(1)] public string Mass { get; set;}
}
```

and this

```cs
public class VoodooOrdinalAttribute : Attribute
{
   public VoodooOrdinalAttribute(int ordinal)
   {
       this.Ordinal = ordinal;
   }
   public int Ordinal { get; set; }
}
```

And expect the order of properies to be

1. Mass
2. Color
3. Shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use an attribute to order properties.  If you define an attribute with a use like you did in your example, here's a LINQ query that orders properties that have the attribute by the number specified in the attribute.

```
var propertyData = from prop in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()
                   let voodooOrdinalAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(VoodooOrdinalAttribute)) as VoodooOrdinalAttribute
                   where voodooOrdinalAttribute != null
                   let lineOrder = voodooOrdinalAttribute.Ordinal
                   orderby lineOrder ascending
                   select prop;
```

Comment: I've edited my question to include the VoodooOrdinalAttribute implementation. How is your query picking up on the order specified by the attribute constructor param and/or property?

Comment: For each property it gets the attribute (first let expression). Then it does a null check (where clause) and then gets the ordinal from the attribute instance for the property (second let expression). Finally it orders the properties in ascending order (orderby clause) and then it selects the property (select clause).

Comment: Ahh... got it.  `.Ordinal` is the name you gave the property on the attribute.  I'll update my question.  Nice work!